# All broadcasts registered for incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, virus

There is a virus in my phone which brings up a popup whenever a call is coming. I want to detect and delete that. 
For this I was thinking maybe i should get all broadcasts registered to Incoming calls, by this i'll get the Application responsible for the virus.
I can use the following code for all broadcast receivers with BOOT_COMPLETE action, but I need this for action ACTION_INCOMING_CALLS.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);

PackageManager pg = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pg.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
```

if you have another solution for the virus as well, let me know.